# Get text when inputing content with Input tag by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I will show you [Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Xwr/) about my program question.

```
<label for="test">Username:</label>
<input type="text" id="test">
<p id=""></p>
```

```js
$("#test").onclick(function(){
    alert('xx');                
})
```

I want to realize this function:
`p` tag real-time displays `input` tag's content when I input something. I'll be very happy if you answer me.

Thank you.

Comment: please explain more about your question.Didnt understand a thing

Comment: use onfocus or onblur.not onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `keyup` event,

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){
         $("#para").html(this.value) ;               
 });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/5TARE/)

Answer (score 1):

You can attach it to the keyup event that way it updates with every keystroke.

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Xwr/1/

```
$("#test").keyup(function(){
        $('#paragraph').html($(this).val());               
 })
```